# How to set Custom URL in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I would like to define a url like below:

http://localhost/bekzcart/books/list?cid=1&type=grid&page=1

How to create a custom route for that type of url, my router code is not work at all

```
Router::connect('/books/list?cid=:cid&type=:type&page=:page', array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'list'));
```

The parameter cid, type, and page is empty, but when i changed to

```
Router::connect('/books/list?:cid&:type&:page', array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'list'));
```

it works, the parameter cid, type, and page is now exist.

**Note: my cake version is 1.3**

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: What are you aiming at? The rule looks like you're trying to convert that type of url to books/list/cid:1/type:grid/page:1.

Comment: yeah but with different style, i like to use old fashioned url but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need those routes, if you need to get those url parameters, you can just get it from `$this->params['url']['param_name']`

If you want the parameters to be readily available as ${param_name} in your method, you can tell routes to pass those params by using pass, like so:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/949/Passing-parameters-to-action

```
// some_controller.php
function view($articleID = null, $slug = null) {
    // some code here...
}

// routes.php
Router::connect(
    // E.g. /blog/3-CakePHP_Rocks
    '/blog/:id-:slug',
    array('controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        // order matters since this will simply map ":id" to $articleID in your action
        'pass' => array('id', 'slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

So in your case, would be something like: (untested)

```
Router::connect('/books/list?cid=:cid&type=:type&page=:page', 
   array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'list'),
   array(
      'pass' => array('cid', 'type', 'page')
   )
);
```

Comment: okay i see, my conclusion is that type of url is not suitable for router

Comment: If you use 'pass', you can directly refer the arguments by its name in your method `$cid`, `$type` and `$page`

Comment: the problem is in `cid=:cid&type=:type&page=:page`, the url parameter is not defined, but it work when i change to `:cid&:type&:page`, the problem is in named paramater.